# Any way to rotate this cat so it was horizontally and look from right to left?

Tags: opengl, julia, wireframe

The [following example](http://juliaplots.org/MakieReferenceImages/gallery//wireframe_of_a_mesh/index.html) draws cat:

```
using AbstractPlotting

wireframe(MakieGallery.loadasset("cat.obj"))
```

Unfortunately, cat looks up vertically:

[image]

is it possible to rotate it normally with mouse or keybord? I found I an unable.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the APIs you're using, but I'd be extremely surprised if there isn't transform functionality available, etc. A quick search led me to the topic of [scenes](http://makie.juliaplots.org/dev/scenes.html#AbstractPlotting.rotate!), and I see some example code [here](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Makie.jl/issues/601). Maybe someone will offer a specific answer, but meanwhile I'd dig further into the tools you're using and see what you can find.

Comment: No, I mean rotate as is, interactively, without transofmations in code

Comment: If you don't want to change the code, load your obj in blender apply 2 rotations in the X and Z axis (as you see fit).  then Ctrl + A -> apply all tranformations. Export back to an updated_cat.obj

Comment: @DraykoonD :D the question is about Julia tools; did they just forgot to add ability to rotate in one of three directions or not?